# Ethernet Interface does not show after fresh installation of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 but my network interface does not show up. I already read several posts so I tried various answers to restart my network like `sudo service network-manager restart`, `sudo ifconfig eno1 up`,... but nothing worked.
The funny thing is that everything works fine if I just reboot the computer. So the drivers are available and the hardware is compatible. This is not a one time thing but I always need to power my PC (no internet), I reboot and I can access the internet without any problems.

**Below I added the output of some commands**:

`ip addr`

(after first boot with no internet)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(after reboot with internet available)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:da:e9:15:28:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.7/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft 86336sec preferred_lft 86336sec
    inet6 fe80::c162:e3cf:f06b:15e0/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`lshw -C network`

(after first boot with no internet)

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 05
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fa600000-fa61ffff memory:fa628000-fa628fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

(after reboot with internet available)

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 14:da:e9:15:28:f9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.2.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:48 memory:fa600000-fa61ffff memory:fa628000-fa628fff ioport:f040(size=32)
```

The outputs of the last two commands have been the same for both cases.
`cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

**Additional info:** I had the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 but I lived with it as I didn't have the time for intensive troubleshooting. I just thought a fresh install and a new Ubuntu might do the trick, especially as Ubuntu 20.04 booted from USB directly uses the interface. But now with a fresh install, the problem persists and I'd like to get rid of it as it is really annoying.

**As requested:**

This is a desktop PC with a P8Z68-V PRO motherboard from ASUSTeK Computer INC.

`sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` returns: 0501

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Laptop? Edit your question and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By accident I found that resetting my bios solved my problem. To be honest I don't know why exactly it helps as I didn't change much but anyway now I can access the internet directly after the first boot without any problems (and without reboot). Maybe it helps someone with a similar issue.